# Problem with Bibtex Page number is too large?

Tags: bibtex

the page number is:

```
year = {2014},
OPTkey = {•},
volume = {53},
OPTnumber = {•},
pages = {12783−12792},
OPTmonth = {•},
OPTnote = {•},
OPTannote = {•}
```

error is with the page number it is shown in the output like this: 1278312792 without a dash.

Comment: You should check if the symbol between `12783` and `12792` is an ordinary `-` hyphen character. If it's not (say because it's a Unicode character that looks like a dash symbol), replace it with the basic `-` (hyphen, dash) character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your bib data and found that the only problem is with the dash or hyphenation character, not the length of the page numbers. Change the field from

```
pages = {12783−12792},
```

to either

```
pages = {12783-12792},
```

or

```
pages = {12783--12792},
```

and it works. (Using double quotes instead of curly braces to delimit the field is OK too.) Observe that the `−` character you had in the field is *not* the same as the "standard" dash character: `-`.

For more information about the dash and its different types, I encourage you to read the following reference:

> Wikipedia contributors, "Dash," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia,
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dash&oldid=630001350
>   (accessed October 23, 2014).

The following question may help to understand why we should use double dashes:

> [Why should I use -​- in pages field of a BibTeX entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58668/why-should-i-use-in-pages-field-of-a-bibtex-entry)

Comment: thanks a lot. I really had no idea on how to solve this its because i think nothing is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing: Are you saying that the solution lies purely in replacing the curly braces with double-quote marks? If this were correct, no bib file that uses curly braces to delimit the contents of fields would be valid...

Comment: @Mico No, the solution lies in replacing - with --, I edited the answer to make it clear.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent - I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to highlight that the problem was with the particular dash character used in the OP's posting. I've also upvoted your answer. :-)

Comment: @Mico thank you so much :-) I edited the answer to link to a wikipedia page about the dash too.